# OpenApi Generator - Spring Security - BearerToken?

Tags: spring, openapi-generator

I'm using the openapi maven-plugin to generate up all the web code and it works fine enough, as long as I don't enable security. Feels like there is code missing on the server and in the client to create the actual bearer token.

OpenAPI spec:

```
openapi: 3.0.3
servers:
  - url: /
security:
  - bearerAuth: [ ]
paths:
  /foo/bar:
    $ref: ./paths/FooBar.yaml

components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
      bearerFormat: JWT
```

pom:

```
 ...
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
            ...
            <execution>
                    <id>generate-server</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                        <library>spring-boot</library>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                        <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                        <generateModels>false</generateModels>
                        <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                        <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                        <apiPackage>${project.parent.groupId}.server</apiPackage>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-client</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                    <library>webclient</library>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                    <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                    <generateModels>false</generateModels>
                    <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                    <generateSupportingFiles>true</generateSupportingFiles>
                    <packageName>${project.parent.groupId}.client</packageName>
                    <apiPackage>${project.parent.groupId}.client</apiPackage>
                    <invokerPackage>${project.parent.groupId}.client.invoker</invokerPackage>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
                ...
        <plugin>
 ...
```

The generated client has functionality for adding an already generated bearer token to requests but no method to request that a bearer token should be created. Have I misunderstood exactly what the openapi generator is capable of and it's as simple as moving the security to path level and create a new endpoint that is unsecured that you can generate the initial token from?